# Such code, Much wow, very FizzBuzz

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz, dogescript

So, I've written FizzBuzz for a dialect of JavaScript called [Dogescript](https://dogescript.com).

It has the same functionality as JavaScript, it simply changes some of the syntax points:

> [[A few from the language spec]](https://github.com/dogescript/dogescript/blob/master/LANGUAGE.md)
>
> ```
> shh [comment] - // [comment]
> very [var] is [value] - var [var] = [value]
> [var] is [value] - [var] = [value]
> such [name] much [variables] - function [name] ([variables])
> wow - }
> rly [params] - if ([params])
> but rly [params] - else if ([params])
> but - else
> ```

I have a feeling I'm misusing the language syntax in relation to adding strings to `result`.

I also have a feeling my underlying structure of:

- Create result variable
- Append `"Fizz"` and `"Buzz"` based on rules
- Print result variable if it has content, otherwise the iterator value.

```
such fizzbuzz much max
    much very i is 0 next i smaller max next i more 1
        very result
        rly i % 3 is 0
            result += "Fizz"
        wow
        rly i % 5 is 0
            result += "Buzz";
        wow
        console.loge(result || i);
    wow
wow
```

You can run this with:

```
plz fizzbuzz with 30
```

Comment: If it has the same functionality as JavaScript and just changes the syntax, why didn't you just write it in JavaScript?

Comment: I wanted to try dogescript... @SimonForsbergMcFeely

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, use the doge version for everything possible:

```
    such fizzbuzz much max
        much very i is 0 next i smaller max next i more 1
            very result
            rly i % 3 is 0
                result more "Fizz" next
            wow
            rly i % 5 is 0
                result more "Buzz" next
            wow
            console dose with result or i next
        wow
    wow
```

As it's a fun fun language, making use of `but rly` is more important than optimizations:

```
    very result
    rly i % 3 is 0
        result is "Fizz" next
    but rly i % 5 is 0
        result is "Buzz" next
    but rly i % 15 is 0
        result is i
```

Making another function for printing instead keeping the `result` variable looks even better:

```
    such print much result 
        console dose loge with result
    wow       


    such fizzbuzz much max
        very i is 1
        much next i smaller max next i more 1
          rly i % 15 is 0
              plz print with "FizzBuzz"
          but rly i % 3 is 0
              plz print with "Fizz"
          but rly i % 5 is 0
              plz print with "Buzz"
          but
              plz print with i
          wow
        wow
    wow
```